# Find Checked Checkbox in Sub Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is menu With three level And I want To Find Checked CheckBox in third Level.I write Function for checked checkbox But Doesnt Work Fine.how can I Do that???

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/7353/

```
  <div class="tree"> <ul>
                    <li class='Root'>
                        <input type='checkbox'/><a href='#' name="Ar">First part</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='Root'>
                                <a id='6' href='#'><input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                                <ul class='SubRoot' >
                                    <li><input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                                    <li><input id='2' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                            <li class='Root'><a id='7' href='#'><input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                                <ul class='SubRoot'>
                                    <li><input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li class='Root'>
                        <input type='checkbox'/><a href='#' name="Ar">First part</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='Root'>
                                <a id='6' href='#'><input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                                <ul class='SubRoot' >
                                    <li><input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
    </ul> </div

            var listPart = [];
            $('.tree >ul>li input:checked').each(function () {
                var A1 = this.id;
                listPart.push(A1);
            });
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what it is that you want a little better. Unfortunately, your description is not very readable.

Comment: do u want just check parents checkbox?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/7355/ what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this selector:

```
$(".SubRoot input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/7354/)

Answer (score 1):

There is some problems, please read the comments in the code to understand them.

```js
function check() {
  var listPart = [];
  var listSec = [];
  var listTA = [];
  $('.tree >ul>li input:checked').each(function () {
    var A1 = this.id;
    listPart.push(A1);

    var Sec = $(this).closest('ul').parent().find('a').attr('id');
    listSec.push(Sec);

    var parentModule = $(this).closest('ul').parent().closest('ul').parent().find('a').attr(/* id - need to replace the `name` */'name');
    listTA.push(parentModule);
  });

  // show the result
  $('#console').html('<p>' + JSON.stringify(listPart) + ',' + JSON.stringify(listSec) + ',' + JSON.stringify(listTA) + '</p>');
}

// run the function whenever checkbox was changed
$(':checkbox').change(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- you forgot the .tree element -->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class='Root'>
            <input type='checkbox' /><a href='#' name="Ar">First part</a>
            <ul>
                <li class='Root'>
                    <a id='6' href='#'>
                        <input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                    <ul class='SubRoot'>
                        <li>
                            <input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                        <li>
                            <input id='2' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='Root'><a id='7' href='#'>
                    <input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                    <ul class='SubRoot'>
                        <li>
                            <input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='Root'>
            <input type='checkbox' /><a href='#' name="Ar">First part</a>
            <ul>
                <li class='Root'>
                    <a id='6' href='#'>
                        <input type='checkbox' />Second part</a>
                    <ul class='SubRoot'>
                        <li>
                            <input id='1' type='checkbox' />Third part</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- show the result -->
<div id="console"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following selector to find checked checkboxes on the third level...

```
$('.tree>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li>input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```